# NodeJS - ES6 - Extend class Error to return my own Type as part of the error response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to extend the class Error and being able to return a custom error with some calls similar to this:

```
throw new Error('MessageGoesHere', ObjectWithOtherResultGoesHere | or NULL, ErrorCode);
```

For instance... let's say we have a method like below (I made it up):

```
    public getInformation(value1: string, value2:string): Promise<MyDataResponse> {
        const promise = this.callFunction2(value1, value2)
        .then(result => {
            return result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                MyDataResponse errorResponse = {
                    field1: value1,
                    field2: value2
                };

                throw new CustomError('Error getting information', errorResponse, 003);
            });

        return Promise.resolve(promise);
    }
```

I want to throw my own CustomError with three fields. For that, I created the following class:

```
export default class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor (message: string, newResultObject: object, status: number) {

      // Calling parent constructor of base Error class.
      super(message);

      // Saving class name in the property of our custom error as a shortcut.
      this.name = this.constructor.name;

      // Capturing stack trace, excluding constructor call from it.
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);

      status = status || 500;

      newResultObject = newResultObject;

    }
}
```

However, I can't do **this.status** nor **this.newResultObject** as they are not part of the Error class so it never returned the values. How should I create my CustomError class then? Should I extend from a different Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is defining the `status` and `newResultObject` properties so you just need to set them.
You just need to change

```
status = status || 500;

newResultObject = newResultObject;
```

to

```
this.status = status || 500;

this.newResultObject = newResultObject;
```

in your class

Comment: Nice! I just forgot two declare these two properties in my class. As soon as I defined them, I was able to do this.status and this.newResultObject. Thanks!